# How to merge a dataframe with MultiIndex into another dataframe in an efficient way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two DataFrames and I would like to take the median of one column grouped by a set of two other columns from dataframe A and then merge the calculated median into dataframe B. Let me explain it using the example below:

I have two `DataFrame`s which look like

```
# DataFrame 1
   pu_c  do_c  fare
0     0     5    10
1     0     5    20
2     1     1     3

# DataFrame 2
   pu_c  do_c
0     0     3
1     0     5
2     1     1
```

I would like to take the median of `fare` grouped by `pu_c` and `do_c` using:

```
a = df1.groupby(['pu_c', 'do_c']).median()['fare']
```

which will result in:

```
pu_c  do_c
0     5       15
1     1        3
```

Now I want to merge the median fare calculated in `a` from `df1` into another dataframe such as `df2`. I know how to do it using the for loops and messy code. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to do it using pandas' `merge` or `concat` functions.

My desired output in this example is

```
   pu_c  do_c  median_fare
0     0     3  NaN (or whatever)
1     0     5  15
2     1     1  3
```

Note: to reproduce my dataframes use:

```
import pandas as pd
pu_c = [0, 0, 1]
do_c = [5, 5, 1]
do_c2 = [3, 5, 1]
fare = [10, 20, 3]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pu_c': pu_c, 'do_c': do_c, 'fare': fare})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'pu_c': pu_c, 'do_c': do_c2})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `a` into a dataframe and rename the values to `median_fare` using `a.to_frame('median_fare')`, reset the index, then do an outer merge with `df2`. It will automatically merge on the 2 columns in common (`do_c` and `pu_c`)

```
df2.merge(a.to_frame('median_fare').reset_index(), how='outer')

   do_c  pu_c  median_fare
0     3     0          NaN
1     5     0         15.0
2     1     1          3.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, `a` is already a `DataFrame` and does not need to turn. `reset_index()` did the trick and let me use `merge`.